# Collapsable Div script. Code not working for multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Wondering, how would I make my code work for multiple collapsable divs without having to create additional instances of the same CSS/JS code?

So far I only managed to make it work for 1 div. Im still new to JS and I love to learn new techniques.

I would be happy to hear some feedback.

```
<input type="button" onclick="growDiv()" value="Read more" id="more-button">
<div id='grow'>
    <div class='measuringWrapper'>
        <div class="text">Testing Collapse Testing Collapse Testing Collapse Testing Collapse Testing Collapse Testing Collapse v Testing Collapse Testing Collapse</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function growDiv() {
    var growDiv = document.getElementById('grow');
    if (growDiv.clientHeight) {
        growDiv.style.height = 0;
    } else {
        var wrapper = document.querySelector('.measuringWrapper');
        growDiv.style.height = wrapper.clientHeight + "px";
    }
    document.getElementById("more-button").value = document.getElementById("more-button").value == 'Read more' ? 'Read less' : 'Read more';
}
```

Here is my JSfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kGs7Q/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use classes not ID's
2. Iterate over the divs once and attach event listeners
3. Use closures to keep references to elements inside the event callbacks

A working example in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sukima/dPGj9/).

For reference here is the HTML/JS:

HTML:

```
<div class="collapsible">
    <input type="button" value="Read more" class="more-button">
    <div class='growable'>
        <div class='measuringWrapper'>
            <div class="text">Testing Collapse Testing Collapse Testing Collapse Testing Collapse Testing Collapse Testing Collapse v Testing Collapse Testing Collapse</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Copy paste as many of these as you wish.

JS:

```
(function() {
    var i, len, collapsibles = document.getElementsByClassName('collapsible');
    for (i = 0, len = collapsibles.length; i < len; i++) {
        (function(collapsible) {
            var button = collapsible.getElementsByClassName('more-button')[0];
            var growDiv = collapsible.getElementsByClassName('growable')[0];
            var wrapper = growDiv.getElementsByClassName('measuringWrapper')[0];
            button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                if (growDiv.clientHeight) {
                    growDiv.style.height = 0;
                }
                else {
                    growDiv.style.height = wrapper.clientHeight + "px";
                }
                button.value = (button.value === 'Read more' ? 'Read less' : 'Read more');
            });
        })(collapsibles[i]);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use classes instead of ids:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="more-button" data-target="[targetID]" value="Read more" />
<div id="[targetID]" class="grow">
    <div class="measuringWrapper">
        [Content]
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function growDiv() {
    var target = this.getAttribute('data-target');
    target = document.getElementById(target);
    if (target.clientHeight) {
        target.style.height = 0;
    } else {
        var wrapper = target.querySelector('.measuringWrapper');
        target.style.height = wrapper.clientHeight + "px";
    }
    this.value = this.value==='Read more'?'Read less':'Read more';
}
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('more-button');
for(var i=els.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
    els[i].onclick = growDiv;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kGs7Q/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `ID`s is great but `ID`s are unique in the `DOM`. For a mufti-functionality you need to switch to using classes and the `this` keyword. Actually the function seems much simpler to me now. Have a look

```
function growDiv(growDiv) {
    var wrapper = growDiv.getElementsByClassName('measuringWrapper')[0],
        label = growDiv.getElementsByClassName('label')[0];

    wrapper.style.height = (wrapper.clientHeight) ? 0 : growDiv.clientHeight + 'px';
    label.innerHTML = label.innerHTML == 'Read more' ? 'Read less' : 'Read more';
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kGs7Q/17/)

Comment: @Oriol I was wondering why it wasn't working. Updating in a sec!